# How to build maven in Docker build file

Tags: java, docker, maven

I have been desperately trying to figure out if it's possible to build a mvn project on a jenkins agent with a docker build file. The error that I am getting from running the pipeline is `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile`

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        dockerfile { 
            filename 'DockerFile.build'
        }
    }
    environment {
        JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.272.b10-1.el8_2.x86_64"
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build DockerFile') {
            steps {
                echo "building docker image"
                sh "echo 1 | alternatives --config java"
                sh "java -version"
                sh "echo ${JAVA_HOME}"

                git branch: "develop", credentialsId: 'cred_id', url: "git@bitbucket.org:repo.git"
                dir("repo"){
                    sh "mvn clean install -X"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

DockerFile.build

```
FROM centos

RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install -y java-11-openjdk-devel
RUN yum install -y java-11-openjdk

RUN yum install -y maven


ENV HOME=${home}
```

The line about `echo 1 | alternatives --config java` is to switch to java 11. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error has a cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
docker {
            image 'maven:3-alpine'
            args '-v $HOME/.m2:/root/.m2'
        }
```

Need to mount the .m2 dir. It's under Caching containers here: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you have a docker build file (`Dockerfile`) that you want to build so you have a reusable image. Once you have the image you can push it to a registry (like Dockerhub) or run it with your application code mounted inside. If you first want to push the image to a registry, you can then pull it down and run it... much the same way as you'd pull any other docker image down and run it.

I answered a similar question recently here: [Dockerfile can't build app with Maven - No goals specified for this build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64511717/dockerfile-cant-build-app-with-maven-no-goals-specified-for-this-build/64516944#64516944)
Perhaps this helps?

Seems like you have an error because you're attempting to build directly on the jenkins host rather than in the docker container with maven/java11 installed.

Its a common mistake to think you're within a docker container on a host, when in fact you're just on the host and the container is running within it without your realising. Check `docker ps -a` if this is the case to get the container ID and then you open a terminal   within it using `docker exec -it bash` or `docker exec -it sh`